# How does DbgView capture kernel debugging messages sent by DbgPrintEx function?

Tags: c, debugging, kernel, windows-kernel

I know that the output from [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (user-mode debugging function) can be captured using the method [outlined here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString). But I can't seem to find how to capture the output from a kernel function [DbgPrintEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprintex) into a user-mode process like [DbgView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) does?

[image]

Comment: *DebugView* use driver - *Dbgv.sys* - it call [`DbgSetDebugPrintCallback`](http://www.ntsecurity.nu/onmymind/2006/2006-06-12.html) (on xp - trampoline in `DbgPrint`). as result, when `DbgPrintEx` called - called callback to *Dbgv.sys*. it notify user mode *debugview*

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, thanks. I [found it myself](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18544/trying-to-understand-this-construct-in-dbgv-sys-driver-for-dbgview-tool). Btw, that driver is a mess.